Preserve stan oil decking
I have decking made up of old scaffold boards. After ten years it is looking tired and some have rotted with rain penetration.  I need confirmation of the procedure for the replacements. I believe wood preserver first and for colour next, on some, I previously mixed up from watered down food colouring or Morrells or Manns water based dye/stain, and then decking oil.
I am just not sure if there will be a problem with the food dye or dyes/stains that are not specific for external wood. I cannot find the wide range of colours in specific external stain that I can with Morrells or Manns. They are also used as a finish whereas I will be protecting the non specified wood stain with the coat of decking oil. Is that going to last or is there an alternative way of staining  the boards before oiling

This is the issue with trying to color exterior wood - it fades rapidly in the sunlight and with foot traffic, then you have to recolor it far too frequently. I'd suggest simply filling/replacing damaged boards and applying clear sealer. Makes ongoing maintenance easier.

In general for outdoor projects you want a pigmented product, as most external coloured finishes are — some are darn close to paint in actual fact, as you might have noticed from how much they obscure the grain of the wood. In terms of real stain (true dye-based stains) there's really nothing that can withstand the full onslaught of sunlight year-round (as horizontal surfaces do) even in Blighty. "is there an alternative way of staining the boards" Yes, with a product such as "decking stain". And yes one of the plusses of using such a product is that you don't then have to use anything else.
